# Disappearing Villagers

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been having a problem in my man-made village where some of my villagers have disappeared. I know zombies aren't the problem because it's lit up, and they can't reach it, but I think the problem might be bad reputation but I'm not sure and don't know much about it.

I really need help because I've lost a level 4 Farmer and a level 4 Librarian which had a mending trade. If you need to see the village I recorded a quick tour:

Comment: I noticed that the villagers who disappeared job site blocks aren't being claimed don't know if that helps

Comment: All of my villagers disappeared except 3 adults and 1 baby while I was AFK for 2 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, It's a bug in bedrock right now.
https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-26338?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

I hope it gets fixed at some point.